# Justification for using polar coordinate with Riemannian metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a $d$ dimensional Riemannian manifold, $\exp_p:V_p\to M$ the exponential map from a neighborhood of $0$ in  $T_pM$ into $M$. Recall that we may assume $\exp_p$ maps $V_p$ diffeomorphically onto an open $U\subset M$.

Let $e_1,\dots,e_d$ be an orthonormal basis of $T_pM$, consider the identification
$$\begin{align}
\Phi:T_pM &\to \Bbb R^d \\
v^ie_i&\mapsto (v^1,\dots,v^d)
\end{align}$$
of $T_pM$ with $\Bbb R^d$. With this identification, $(\exp_p^{-1},U)$ is a chart centered at $p$, called the **normal coordinates**.

In Jost's *Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis*, there's the following theorem:

> **Theorem 1.4.4** In normal coordinates, we have for the Riemannian metric
>   $$\begin{align}
> g_{ij}(0) &= \delta_{ij} \\
> \Gamma^i_{jk}(0) &= 0 \qquad \text{for all}\ i,j,k.  
> \end{align}$$

The proof is not hard to understand, what I struggle with is what follows. In his book, he moves on to apply the theorem for the standard polar coordinates (the definition of this standard polar coordinate is never given)
$$
(r,\varphi^1,\dots,\varphi^{d-1})
$$
where $(\varphi^1,\dots,\varphi^{d-1})$ parametrizes the sphere $S^{d-1}$.

Using theorem 1.4.4, he claims that

> $$
> g_{rr}(0)=1,\ g_{r\varphi}(0)=0
> $$

without further explanation. I don't see how the theorem applies since by the definition of normal coordinates requires that the $\exp_p^{-1}$ is one-to-one onto its image, but the polar coordinate is not one-to-one for $r\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ no matter how small $\varepsilon$ is because the issue at $r=0$. How do we justify the use of theorem 1.4.4 in this case?

**Related:** To my understanding, there's no "global coordinates chart" for a sphere $S^{d-1}$ (or any nontrivial dimension for that matter), so how do we rigorously define $(\varphi^1,\dots,\varphi^{d-1})$ so that $(r,\varphi^1,\dots,\varphi^{d-1})$ make sense? Yes we can patch things up but would that lead to a non-global description of $g_{ij}$ in this particular coordinates system? How do we deal with $r=0$?

**Note:** I realize that Gauss Lemma can be used to prove the statement (and even a stronger claim), but that isn't my question. I want to know how can the proof in Jost's book be justified.

Comment: I agree that the explanation in Jost is not very precise.  But the statement is correct; it should be interpreted as a limit ($\lim_{r\to 0}g_{rr}=1$) since $g_{rr}$ is really defined on the set $\{r>0\}$.

Comment: @macbeth If we interpret it the way you suggested, how can theorem 1.4.4 be applied though? The statement of 1.4.4 only involve $g_{ij}$ at $p$, the center of our chart. It doesn't say anything about any points nearby so how do we take limit?

Comment: Yes, I'm not convinced that the approach Jost takes here is correct (all the facts he mentions are true, but maybe the sequence of deductions is not).  I would suggest just consulting another reference.

Comment: @macbeth Thanks, I was also not convinced but I've just started studying Riemannian geometry so I wasn't sure. Regardless, what do you think about my related question. How should we think of "parametrization of sphere" in general?

Comment: That part is fine -- any parametrization of the sphere works.

Comment: I mean any parametrization is going to leave out at least one point on the sphere (or maps different points to the same point on sphere). How do we define $g_{ij}$ at this point then? By taking limit? Also if it's the later case then is $g_{ij}$ at that point uniquely defined?

Comment: @macbeth I apologize if the question seems silly, I have no experience with working in coordinate before.

Comment: Again, this is a point on which Jost's presentation is morally correct but perhaps not literally so.  The parametrization can leave out some points on the sphere, that's ok, so long as you follow through with appropriate adjustments, in, eg, Corollary 1.4.2.  Again, you might want to see if another presentation is more to your taste -- for example, I find John Lee's books to be consistently careful on points like these.

Comment: Look in Chavel's book, "Riemannian Geometry: A Modern Introduction." Section 1.6.

Comment: The basic idea is to write the tangent space, $T_x M \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $x \in M$ in polar coordinates, and then compose them with the exponential map to get polar coordinates on $M$. As you note, Jost's proof can be justified by Gauss' lemma. In fact $g_{rr} = 1$, $g_{r\varphi} = 0$ is effectively just a restatement of Gauss' lemma, so it would seem the only way to prove it is by Gauss' lemma.

Comment: @BigbearZzz, I have yet to find a rigorous *and* readable introduction to differential (and Riemannian) geometry. I advise against Chavel's cited book, and avoid Berger's "A panoramic view of Riemannian geometry" at all costs! If you want rigour, but are ready to sacrifice intuition, try the classic "Kobayashi & Nomizu".